# Visualize (plot) Dataset csv using PCA on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pca

I have the folowing code which show a list of spam/ham messages from a csv file ...

`data = pd.read_csv('spam.csv', encoding='latin-1', delimiter='\t', header=None)
data`

[image]

I want to show a plot (cluster) of my csv dataset by using a PCA, something like this (where the green are spam and blue ham for example)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can map your 'ham' and 'spam' labels to categories and then use [`matplotlib.pyplot.scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) to do a scatter plot. This makes it relatively easy to add new labels as well in the future.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# map 'ham' and 'spam' labels to numbers
df['label_num'] = df['ham/spam'].map({ 'ham': 0, 'spam': 1 })

# scatter plot
plt.scatter(df['x'], df['y'], cmap='rainbow', c=df['label_num'])
```

Comment: And what im u supposed to put on x and y ?

Comment: What did you originally intend on plotting on your x and y-axis? It's not clear from the dataframe you provided

Comment: my csv file has a total of 4,827 ham messages and a total of 747 spam, i want to show the frequency of both of them on a plot, with 2 different colors. For that I have 2 columns, ham/spam,  message and the column label_num (# map 'ham' and 'spam' labels to numbers) ... thnx :)

Comment: perhaps a bar graph would be more appropriate for your data instead of a scatter plot?

Comment: Ok ... I think that i did not quite understand the question. thnxs for help !

Comment: I I did not formulate my question well so i try again ... Do u think that i can make a visualization of my spam/ham data using   PCA from sklearn.decomposition?   It can be something like this ...    
                                                    
sklearn.decomposition import PCA

for t,marker,c in zip(target_ids, ">ox*", "rgbc"):
plt.scatter(pca_data[target==t,0], pca_data[target==t,1], marker=marker, c=c)